# Is there a way to force caching of javascript / css with GET parameters?

Tags: windows, firefox, browser-cache

There are some pages on the internet that I want to load as fast as possible, but caching of their dozens of javascript/css files is being thwarted by the presence of GET parameters on the resource urls. eg: `SomeCSSFile?v=1983745932203&language=English`.

I am willing to go to great lengths to try and circumvent this behavior, but so far I can't come up with anything.

I have tried:

- Firefox Settings that allow caching urls with GET parameters - no such option exists (probably since it would violate the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.9).
- Some Firefox add-on that offers this functionality. I have found none.
- Greasemonkey scripts - but by then it's too late, the document is ready and all resources have been loaded, so removing the get parameters at this point is useless.
- Some Firefox add-on that allows pre-processing retrieved HTML before it is processed by Firefox. I have found none.
- Client caching software that I can install (such as [Varnish Cache](https://www.varnish-cache.org/releases/varnish-cache-3.0.5) - which is only available on Linux based operating systems.) I have found none.

Server side solutions are of course no good, as I do not control the source of the pages in question.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, a parameter like `v` in your example is often used *specifically to prevent caching* so that you always get a new copy instead instead of a cached copy. Of course that is supposed to be used for things like login pages and such, but some web developers use it indiscriminately even where it is not needed. As far as I can figure, it would require a browser or proxy server or something that is specifically designed to counteract this salting, but that’s hard to implement because it would require somehow figuring out what URLs are the “same” which depends on the site.

Comment: @Synetech I'm willing to set up a proxy server to do this and implement my own rules, just point me in the right direction. I looked at `squid` too, which is similar to Varnish but used to have a windows port, but that's long dead.

Comment: @Synetech, that isn't even my gaol. I want `blah.html?a=1` to be treated the same as another request for `blah.html?a=1` and loaded from a cache. w3c specifies that the presence of any get parameter at all makes a query un-cacheable, which is why Firefox and other major browsers don't cache these requests. the `v=...` in my example is a version number. It never changes. There is no reason not to cached it. I gave an example of software (Varnish) which is configurable to cache requests with the same GET parameters. I'm looking for a similar solution for Windows.

Comment: The problem is that it depends on what the server sends. The browser or proxy would have to ignore and violate the rule on purpose. The only references I can find are [from developers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877339/) trying to [allow their sites to be cached](http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/get-parameters-and-caching/) for users, not the other way around.

Comment: Well if it helps, imagine I'm polling reddit hundreds of times a minute so that I can be the very first to see when the best joke in the world is posted. I can poll for the actual content much faster if I cache their javascript and css rather than fetching it each time. I know it's not changing and even if it were, I don't care, but I can't just remove them entirely (for instance using adblock) or the site becomes non-functional.

Comment: Yes, I know, but like I said, the only thing I can find to do that is from the other side of the equation. In your example, it would be Reddit trying to find out how they can make their scripts and stylesheets and [images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285354/) cache. There doesn’t *seem* to be any browsers or caches that are designed to cache no matter what. There are a few [sort-of–similar questions](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asuperuser.com+save+webpages+offline) that could help.